# Заполнение массива с помощью Prepare for Segue

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

Есть ViewController, в котором я добавляю значения из textfiled в массив.
И нужно передать и отобразить значения этого массива в другом TableViewController используя segue.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!

var names: [String] = []

@IBAction func saveButtonText(_ sender: Any) {

    var error = ""

    if (textfield.text?.isEmpty)! {
        error = "поле пустое"
    }

    if error != "" {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ошибка", message: "У вас \(error)!!!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Хорошо", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        textfield.placeholder = "У вас \(error)!!!"
    } else {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "backTableView", sender: self)
        names.append(textfield.text!)
        print(names)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "addNewLabel" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! TableViewController
            destinationVC.name = names
    }
}
```

}

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var name: [String] = []

@IBAction func returnTableView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return name.count
}


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.namesLabel.text = name[indexPath.row]

    return cell
    }
```

}

Comment: А в чем проблема то?

Comment: Не получается передать значения из заполненного массива в пустой для отображения значений в таблице.

Comment: На первый взгляд код верный. print(names) выводит все верно? Возможно Вы не указали нужный тип контроллера в сториборде?

Comment: Да принт выводит верно, думаю, что проблема в unwind segue, через индефикатор которого я выхожу из экрана.

Comment: Так у Вас view, куда вы передаете массив не является UITableViewController? У Вас в сториборде кто владелец контроллера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый день!
Сначала добавьте строку в массив names и только после этого попробуйте вызывать performSegue + reloadData в ViewController и perform Segue для передачи массива name:
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!

```
var names: [String] = []

@IBAction func saveButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    var error = ""

            if (textfield.text?.isEmpty)! {
                error = "поле пустое"
            }

            if error != "" {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ошибка", message: "У вас \(error)!!!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Хорошо", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(okAction)
                present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                textfield.placeholder = "У вас \(error)!!!"
            } else {
                names.append(textfield.text!)
                print(names)
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "backTableView", sender: self)

            }
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "backTableView" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! TableViewController
        destinationVC.name = names
    }
}
```

}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var name: [String] = []
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return name.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) 
    cell.textLabel?.text = name[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
@IBAction func returnTableView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    self.tableView .reloadData()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "addNewLabel" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ViewController
        destinationVC.names = name
    }
}
```

}

Архив:
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/BNZ6/XFL7uEPy2

Comment: Тоже не работает.
Не, не опечатка "performSegue(withIdentifier: "backTableView", sender: self)", я через индефикатор unwind segue выхожу из ViewControllerа после добавления значения в массив.

Comment: Принтскрин storyboard-a пришлите.

Comment: Вот https://monosnap.com/file/D11S8rtNj1RHOC6q3Ho3SMggpaXuQ8

Comment: В TableView надо добавить 2 метода: `@IBAction func returnTableView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        self.tableView .reloadData()
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "addNewLabel" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ViewController
            destinationVC.names = name
        }
    }` В ViewController оба идентификатора должны иметь название backTableView

Comment: Спасибо, все разаботало!